# How to make a rectangle scale twice in android

Tags: android-animation

I have a rectangle that i know how to scale through animation in xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="5.0" />

</set>
```

But the problem is even if I do this

```
public void practice(View view) {
        View test = (View) findViewById(R.id.view1);
        Animation scale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),             
        R.anim.scale);
        scale.setFillAfter(true);
        scale.setFillBefore(true);
        test.startAnimation(scale);
     }
```

It will only allow me to grow a rectangle once and stay that scale only once. I want it in such that everytime I grow the rectangle, i make scale it again to a bigger size. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. However, I think the problem is that you declare the View within the practice function. This means it will reload each time and then scale. I think you want to declare the view outside the function (eg. in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`) and call `practice(test)` where you need it.